# Global dimension of a subalgebra with all units

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, dimension-theory

*(All rings here are always assumed to be unital and associative).*

---

### Setup

Let $R$ be a ring, and $A$ and $B$ be $R$-algebras, with $A$ a commutative subalgebra of $B$ satisfying:

1. *If $u$ is a unit in $B$, then $u$ is in $A$.*
2. If $\mathfrak{F}_A$ and $\mathfrak{F}_B$ are the smallest free algebras admitting canonical projection *(R-algebra)* morphisms $\pi_A:\mathfrak{F}_A \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_B: \mathfrak{F}_B \rightarrow B$ respectivly; then, $\mathfrak{F}_A$ must be a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{F}_B$.

---

### Question:

**Can anything be deduced about *the global dimension $D(B)$ of $B$, with respect to $D(A)$?***

---

### Hypothesis & Some Test Results:

I'm strongly inclined to believe, that in such a situation $D(R)\geq D(A)$, for example this hold for the Weyl algebra $A_n(k)$ and $k[x_1,..,x_n]$.
For $R[x_1,..,x_n]$ and $Z(R)[x_1,...,x_n]$...

Moreover, any "counter example" where $A$ is a subring of $B$ and $D(A)\not\leq D(B)$ is generated from an example where $A$ does not contain some unit of $B$, for example any $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra as relating to any $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.  Or assumes $A$ to be a subalgebra of $B$ with "more relations" which is not possible by the assumptions $1$ and $2$, respectively.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but isn't $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x]$ a counterexample?

Comment: Nope... I rephrased my question, to make it clearer that no new relations can be introduced... so in this sense $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ would not be a counterexample since it is not trivially related and yet $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is.

Comment: I think your edit has several typos, but if $\pi$ is surjective, how can $\pi'$ be surjective if $A\neq B$?

Comment: Sorry about that I typed quicker than I thought, ok I fixed up the details and the question should all be in order now :)

Comment: You call $\iota'$ an inclusion, but it's not automatically injective (if it is, then so is $j$, obviously). And $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are not uniquely determined, so it's conceivable that the injectivity depends on the choice. Is the hypothesis that there is some choice of $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ such that $\iota'$ is injective? Also, I think some of the maps in your diagram are mislabelled, and is "$A$ is some unit of $B$" in the last paragraph a typo?

Comment: Yes the injectiveness of "$j$" is *"part of the hypothesis"*; in that, it is an immediate consequence of the assumptions on $\iota$ and $\iota'$ and the snake lemma).  
Thanks for spotting that typo *(I was just attempting to motivate assumption $1$ and $2$ in that last paragraph)*.

Comment: Did you mean to drop the "smallest possible" condition on $\mathfrak{F}_A$ and $\mathfrak{F}_B$ in your last edit? If so, then you can make $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x]$ into a counterexample by choosing a reduntantly large set of generators for $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: oops, ok I put those crucial assumptions back in

Comment: There's still the problem that the hypotheses allow non-trivial choice in the selection of $\pi_A$, $\pi_B$ and $\iota'$ which can affect whether or not $\iota'$ and $j$ are injective. For example, for a field $k$, take $A=k[x^2,x^3]$, $\mathfrak{F}_A=k\langle u,v\rangle$ with $\pi_A(u)=x^2$, $\pi_A(v)=x^3$, $B=k[x,s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2]$, $\mathfrak{F}_B=k\langle x,s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2\rangle$ with the obvious $\pi_B$. Then the obvious choice of $\iota'$ isn't injective, but there are choices that are: e.g., $\iota'(u)=x^2+s_1s_2-s_2s_1$ and $\iota'(v)=x^3+t_1t_2-t_2t_1$.

Comment: By the way, I'm not just nit-picking for the sake of it. I suspect the example in my last comment might not settle what you want to know (which is why I didn't post it as an answer), although it's a counterexample to one interpretation of what you ask. But if not, then I'm not clear exactly what you do mean by a subalgebra of an algebra  having "more relations".

Comment: I'm happy your stressing the details, its important.   

Essentially what I want clause $2$ to state, is that:  by "more relations" I mean that if $\mathfrak{F}$ is the smallest free algebra projecting (canonically) onto A, then there cannot be a smaller free algebra projecting (canonically) onto B (which is not the case of $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$ since the smallest free algebra projecting onto the former is $\mathbb{C}<x,y>$ and the smallest projecting onto the later is $\mathbb{C}<x>$ (namely itself, up to isomorphism)).

Comment: So does my example above with $A=k[x^2,x^3]$ and $B=k[x,s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2]$ satisfy what you want?